# Getting data from sql table inside a GridView (C#)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

I've got a `GridView` which I made in ASP.NET. Now I want it to fill itself with this method. But it doesn't work. the `return()` doesn't work and the `GetData` inside the `Page_load` is also underlined red(Compiler Error CS1501).

```
 public partial class Pages_GridView1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetData();
    }


    public string GetData(Chart chart)
    {

        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CRM_SQL"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand(chart.Sql, conn);
        SqlDataReader rst = query.ExecuteReader();


        gridView1.DataSource = rst;
        gridView1.DataBind();
        return gridView1();

    }
}
```

Comment: Your `GetData` expect a `Chart` parameter. Have you _ever_ read your error message? If you have an error message, read it carefully. Understand it. If you don't get it, search it. All error messages and exceptions are there for us.

Comment: Sorry i didn't see that.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `GetData()` method without any parameters and then in method definition using `GetData(Chart chart)`.
Plus you are returning string in method definition!!

Method call : `GetData()`
Method definition : `public string GetData(Chart chart)`

Method call and definition should match

Now you should do something like this :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetData();
}


public void GetData()
{
    Chart chart = new Chart();
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CRM_SQL"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand(chart.Sql, conn);
    SqlDataReader rst = query.ExecuteReader();


    gridView1.DataSource = rst;
    gridView1.DataBind();


}
```

**Note : I am assuming you are setting sql query in Chart class**

Comment: So I now get an error in the line "SqlDataReader rst = query.ExecuteReader();"  because the executereader doesn't work

Comment: It is because, it accepts sql query, where are you giving that!! In Chart class or somewhere else

Comment: The sql query should come from the database over the class chart(chart.Sql)

Comment: @fusionchart_help then show us your SQl code inside your `chart.Sql`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify commandtype if you are using stored procedure.

```
SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand(chart.Sql, conn);
query.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlDataReader rst = query.ExecuteReader();
```

Your error is clearly visible.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetData();
    }
```

And signature for GetData is different.

```
 public string GetData(Chart chart)
```

Comment: still the same error, but could it be that gridview1 is not the right return?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a need of returning a string if it is not used. Also  `return`gridView1(); doesn't return a string. It will return `GridView`.
You could either return Gridview i.e. Change the function definition to

```
public Gridview GetData()
```

OR you can do this;
the following code should do the job.

```
public void GetData()
{

    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CRM_SQL"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand(chart.Sql, conn);
    SqlDataReader rst = query.ExecuteReader();


    gridView1.DataSource = rst;
    gridView1.DataBind();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to change method return type to GridView class, because you are returning gridview1 object rite.. and check the method signature you are using is correct or not while calling the method..